# Inexplicable performance difference in Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, optimization, game-development

Scenario: I have a simple scene with around 15k tris (depending on where you look), using Legacy Difuse shaders.
I run the game on a **Galaxy S5** Android 6.0.1. From GSM Arena:

- released 2014, April
- Chipset   Qualcomm MSM8974AC Snapdragon 801  (28 nm)
- CPU   Quad-core 2.5 GHz Krait 400
- GPU   Adreno 330

Getting 50 FPS average
Profiler screenshots
[image]
[image]

I run the game on a **Lenovo P2** Android 7.0. GSM Arena:

- Released 2016, November
- Chipset   Qualcomm MSM8953 Snapdragon 625 (14 nm)
- CPU   Octa-core 2.0 GHz Cortex-A53
- GPU   Adreno 506

Getting 38 FPS average
Profile screenshots
[image]
[image]

What I've tried so far:

- replace the legacy difuse shader with mobile difuse -> both phones gain 10 fps, same performance gap
- disable auto graphics api and force GLES2 - no difference
- force GLES3 - no difference
- tried using the Snapdragon profiler to make a snapshot capture but it keeps crashing when I try to take the snapshot
- forcing the same resolution on both devices (1080), no change  (I was thinking that Unity might do some magic and downscale on the S5), also note that both phones are 1080p

Unity 2018.3.0f2

Same game, same graphics profiles (preferences), same everything. How is this possible?

This is just a stripped down main menu of the game. The main scene of the game (a city with 80k tris on average, and many Standard shaders, runs at over 40 FPS on GS5, and at 28-30 on P2 :/. I also tried the city scene on a Xperia XA2 (slightly better specs than the P2) and it runs at around 56-60 fps)

PS: Notice in the screenshots how because of looking at a different area, **the S5 renders more things on screen**, yet still has so much more FPS than the P2

// Edit Updated thread with the missing info from comments bellow

Comment: Unity version ?

Comment: @Shaman Unity 2018.3.0f2, good point there, forgot to add the version

Comment: Android version?

Comment: @Shaman Haha :D, Lenovo P2 - Android 7.0, Galaxy S5 - 6.0.1,, both have MSAA disabled in settings

Comment: What happens if you turn off v-sync? Might be that the Lenovo doens't handle it all that well (player prefs > quality > vsync count)

Comment: V Sync is disabled already in player prefs, If V Sync was on you would see it in the screenshots as "gfx.waitForTargetFPS"